# Can you create a Variable directly in an Airflow Dag

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

As I understand it, a common Airflow workflow is to create a Variable in the UI and access it in a dag as needed. If for some reason you need to update this variable, you can simply `Variable.set("foo", bar)`.

Is there any way to create a fresh variable in a dag?

Psuedo:

```
def create_new_client_config(client_name):
    data = get_client_details(client_name)
    client_config = Variable.create(f"{client_name}", data)
    client_config.save()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Variable.set("my_key", "my_value")` is used for variables creation as well (not only for update)

Comment: thanks, I thought I was getting a "variable undefined" error in the UI when trying this way but can't reproduce so guess I was being dumb.